# Input date que solo acepte personas mayores de 18 años en php

Tags: php, java, ajax

Estoy realizando un formulario para agregar un personal administrativo pero necesito que al momento de ingresar la fecha de nacimiento solo permita ingresar a mayores de 18 años y si es menor se muestre un mensaje o algo y se regrese al input date vacío y que no permita guardar la información en caso de que no sea mayor edad intente poniendo en el campo input el "max" pero me dijeron que no estaba bien ya que si ponía una fecha máxima cada año tendría que estar actualizando ese rango

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head><body>
        <section id="container">
            <div class="form_register1">
                <div class="alert"><?php echo isset($alert) ? $alert : ''; ?></div><h1><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i> Registro de personal</h1></div>
                <div class="titulo4"></div>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formulario_registro" autocomplete="off">
<label for="Numero de cedula">Cédula de identidad: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="text" name="cedula_empleado" id="ced" placeholder="Nro de cedula" onkeypress="return SoloNumeros(event);" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Primer nombre"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Primer nombre: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="text" name="nombrec_usuario" id="Primer nombre" placeholder="Primer nombre" onkeypress="return SoloLetras(event);" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Segundo nombre">Segundo nombre: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="text" name="nombred_usuario" id="Segundo nombre" placeholder="Segundo nombre" onkeypress="return SoloLetras(event);" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Primer apellido">Apellido paterno: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="text" name="papellido_usuario" id="Primer apellido" placeholder="Primer apellido" onkeypress="return SoloLetras(event);" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Segundo apellido">Apellido materno: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="text" name="sapellido_usuario" id="Segundo apellido" placeholder="Segundo apellido" onkeypress="return SoloLetras(event);" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Fecha de nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="date" name="fnac_usuario" id="Fecha de nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="E-mail">E-mail: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="email" name="email" id="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Numero celular"><i class="fa fa-phone-square"></i> Número celular: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label>
<input type="text" name="celular_empleado" id="Numero celular" placeholder="Nro celular" onkeypress="return SoloNumeros(event);" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="Clave">Contraseña: <a style="color: red;">*</a></label><input type="text" id="Clave" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="&#128190; Guardar" class="btn_save">
                </form></div></section></body></html>
```

Comment: No hacia falta que repitieras la pregunta, el resultado puede ser el mismo, que te la cierren porque no estas mostrando lo que has hecho ni el error que te ha dado. Simplemente nos estas pasando la tarea, y aquí no hacemos tareas. Prueba de entender esto y aplicarlo, y si tienes problemas editas la pregunta y nos pones lo que has hecho con esto y que te falla: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091965/10382744  Lo siento, son las normas del sitio.